# Make android load specific parts of library starting from specific SDK version

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have an app, that must be working on Android 4+. However I want to add some functionality to this app that uses api appeared only in Android 5. So I made a separate module that has higher minSdk version. But when I include this module in app it crashed on startup (fails with app verifier).
How should I tell android class loader to load classes from this module only starting from some another SDK version.

Comment: Vokulov you should wrap around in your code with checking if SDK version fits use classes and calls from newer version.

Like this: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    // call classes from lollipop and further.
}

Comment: The problem was with Camera2 api - crashed on startup even I have not started using it. Found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374939/android-application-with-camera2-library-crash-on-start-for-sdk19