# Crash using CameraX library android: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, android-camerax

I am making a simple camera application using new Jetpack library CameraX. 
As soon as I launch the application just by adding dependencies it is crashing.

Dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-alpha06"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-alpha06"
```

Crash Logs:

```
2019-11-28 16:16:45.828 26428-26428/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ananth.camerax, PID: 26428
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera2Initializer: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera2Initializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ananth.camerax-5fK5oVGKPPgZn_ITpYwEsA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ananth.camerax-5fK5oVGKPPgZn_ITpYwEsA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6444)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5946)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5858)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1690)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6698)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera2Initializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ananth.camerax-5fK5oVGKPPgZn_ITpYwEsA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ananth.camerax-5fK5oVGKPPgZn_ITpYwEsA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6420)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5946) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5858) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1690) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6698) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782) 
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.ananth.camerax-5fK5oVGKPPgZn_ITpYwEsA==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.ananth.camerax-5fK5oVGKPPgZn_ITpYwEsA==/base.apk': Bad method handle type 7
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:681)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:714)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:941)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2254)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5755)
            ... 8 more
```

I cannot find any answers for this on SO.

Comment: Probably this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/56394270/5933012

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA I am not targeting API < 21 still I'll give it a try.

Comment: try to implement the 1.0.0 without the alpha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to your app level `build.gradle` within `android { }`

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

**ERROR:**

```
// CameraX
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta07"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha20"
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
// CameraX
def camerax_version = '1.0.0-rc01'
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha20"
```

Comment: This worked, but I also followed Android Studio's suggestion to use version 1.1.0-alpha04